# “Had started” or “Started”?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

> As the bath oil facility is where the fire **had started,** its proximity to the island fruit trees means the fires spread onto the orchard farm.

I didn’t use “has started” because it’s already done. I’m also narrating in the present tense. But I’m seesawing between “had started” and “started.” Which one should I use?

Comment: Narrating in the present tense, _started_ is appropriate. (The facility _was_ where the fire _had started_.)

Comment: 'Had started' works because it's prior to 'the fires [then] spread'. But since logic adequately spells out the sequence of events, the 'you may and most people do use past simple where the past perfect isn't really needed for clarity' rule applies.

Comment: I would replace 'as' with 'since'... It's more natural.